# oauth2 and basic auth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I use spring boot 2.4.6 with spring security.

Actually we use oauth 2

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
            .and() // (1)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated() // (2)
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt() // (3)
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
    }
}
```

For some endpoint, I need to support a login / password.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up multiple HttpSecurity instances, each matching one or more paths and implementing different authentication schemes. You can add them as separate inner classes extending from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. See [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#multiple-httpsecurity) for more information and an example.

Make sure to include an `@Order` if order matters. In your provided example, the config is generic and matches all requests, so it should be `@Order(2)`. The additional config would be `@Order(1)` and start with `http.antMatcher("/some/path/**").formLogin()...` or similar.

Note: Similar (older) questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815015/creating-multiple-http-sections-in-spring-security-java-config) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233192/how-to-use-spring-security-for-multiple-login-scenarios-with-java-configuration).